# How to solve this trigonometry question

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: The question is in this image link]

This question was in the trigonometry lesson exercise, but at first I thought it will be easily solved as a geometric proof by proving that the two triangles are similar (~) as all the corresponding angles are equal in measure . then finding the side length $CD$ by the similarity ratios between each two corresponding side lengths. Is it right enough or should I use the tan of the two equal alternate angles to find $CD$?

**Note** : the two ways give the same answer : length of $CD = \frac{40}{3} cm$

Comment: They are not similar. You can find a length and an angle in triangle BCD and go from there.

Comment: $\angle{ADB}=\angle{CBD}$, so you can then use their $tan()$ value to solve.

Comment: why aren't they similar ? @Paul

Comment: Well, I think they are similar. And I think your question is not about mathematics. As this is asked in trigonometry lesson, you are supposed to use trigonometry. But in general, you can use any method. Also there are numerous ways to solve a problem.

Comment: Thanks very much MR/ @ACB

Comment: They're similar, as they're right triangles with equal acute angles. This being said, do  you really need to use trigonometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangles are similar. (How?)

$$\frac{AD}{BD}=\frac{AB}{DC}\Rightarrow \frac{6}{BD}=\frac{8}{DC}\Rightarrow DC=\frac{4}{3}BD=\frac{4}{3}\times10=\frac{40}{3}$$